# Creating a Custom SharePoint Picture Library from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, picture-library, developer

Currently I have created a custom Picture User-control, and retrieving images from Picture Library,.

Now I'm trying to create Picture Library from Visual Studio, means Picture Library must be created from solution.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some R&D Found Artical [SharePoint 2013 Custom Picture Library Creation & Deployment](http://technostropic.com/2014/05/29/sharepoint-2013-custom-picture-library-creation-deployment/)

All My requirments Covered in above artical

Answer (score 2):

You can create in two ways. One using list definition (xml) files or using Object Model.

Below is a snippet to create library using object model

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web; //or create SPWeb object
web.Lists.Add("LibName", "Description", SPListTemplateType.PictureLibrary);
web.QuickLaunchEnabled = true; //false to not display in left nav
web.Update();
```

You can add this code inside a feature receiver.